# Как залить фон в SVG вокруг объекта?

Tags: svg

Как залить фон в SVG вокруг объекта так, чтобы фон внутри объекта - остался прозрачным? примерно так, только без скругления углов. Спасибо! https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/246717/bookmark_favorite_square_star_icon#size=256

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мда.. Любую ерунду продавать ухитряются...

Answer (score 4):

## Берём [рядом](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/763279/bookmark_common_favorite_favorites_favourite_star_icon#size=128) бесплатную звезду (хотя я бы сам сделал):

```html
<svg height="24px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><title/><desc/><defs/><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="miu" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"><g id="Artboard-1" transform="translate(-683.000000, -263.000000)"><g id="slice" transform="translate(215.000000, 119.000000)"/><path d="M694.98491,281.136378 L688.186537,286 L690.536373,277.987539 L684,272.561762 L691.949829,272.493347 L694.98491,264 L697.936034,272.561768 L706,272.561768 L699.433447,278.040327 L701.783283,286 L694.98491,281.136378 L694.98491,281.136378 Z" fill="#000000" id="common-star-favorite-bookmark-glyph"/></g></g></svg>
```

и чистим:

```css
body { margin: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue); }
svg { display: block; height: 100vmin; width: 100vmin; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
    <g transform="translate(-683.000000, -263.000000)">
      <path d="M694.98491,281.136378 L688.186537,286 L690.536373,277.987539 L684,272.561762 L691.949829,272.493347 L694.98491,264 L697.936034,272.561768 L706,272.561768 L699.433447,278.040327 L701.783283,286 L694.98491,281.136378 L694.98491,281.136378 Z" fill="#000000" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

и ещё чистим:

```js
console.log(
"M694.98491,281.136378 L688.186537,286 L690.536373,277.987539 L684,272.561762 L691.949829,272.493347 L694.98491,264 L697.936034,272.561768 L706,272.561768 L699.433447,278.040327 L701.783283,286 L694.98491,281.136378 L694.98491,281.136378 Z"
.replace(/(\d+\.?\d*),(\d+\.?\d*)/g, (m,x,y)=>`${(x-683).toFixed(3)},${(y-263).toFixed(3)}`)
)
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue); }
svg { display: block; height: 100vmin; width: 100vmin; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="#000" d="M11.985,18.136 L5.187,23.000 L7.536,14.988 L1.000,9.562 L8.950,9.493 L11.985,1.000 L14.936,9.562 L23.000,9.562 L16.433,15.040 L18.783,23.000 L11.985,18.136 L11.985,18.136 Z" />
</svg>
```

## Теперь добавляем прямоугольник `M0,0H24V24H-24Z`:

При этом надо обратить внимание, что выставлен `fill-rule="evenodd"`.

```css
body { margin: 0; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue); }
svg { display: block; height: 100vmin; width: 100vmin; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="#000" d="M0,0H24V24H-24ZM11.985,18.136 L5.187,23.000 L7.536,14.988 L1.000,9.562 L8.950,9.493 L11.985,1.000 L14.936,9.562 L23.000,9.562 L16.433,15.040 L18.783,23.000 L11.985,18.136 L11.985,18.136 Z" />
</svg>
```

## Готово!

Answer (score 2):

Если работать в Incscape можно создать квадрат с закруглёнными краями, а на него наложить звезду

[image: два объекта]

а дальше в меню Контур, предварительно выбрав оба объекта Shift-ом, нажать Разность.
[image: меню Контур]
Должно получиться именно то, что вы хотите!

Answer (score 2):

Фигуру внутри `clipPath` необходимо создать так, чтобы вначале обойти все крайние точки блока и вернуться в начальную, а затем уже приступить к вырезанию. Для удобства использованы относительные единицы измерения и анимация для иллюстрации выреза.

```css
body {
  animation: bg 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes bg {
  from {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1 
                       0,0 
                       .50,.02 .39,.35 .02,.35 .32,.57 .21,.91 .50,.70 .79,.91 .68,.57 .98,.35 .61,.35
                       .5,.02"></polygon>
      
      
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Но зачем тут clip-path?

Comment: Чтобы вырезать из фигуры другую фигуру, очевидно.

Comment: Но ведь гораздо эффективнее не вырезать, а сделать нужную форму сразу?

Comment: Я видел ваш вариант, если вы об этом.

Comment: Кроме моего варианта есть вариант нарисовать именно ту область, которая нужна (без evenodd). Ещё есть вариант с маской. А `clip-path` мне кажется наиболее накладным. Его лучше для других целей использовать. Или я не прав?

Comment: Ну, я не претендую на то, что это решение супер-лаконичное, просто первое, что пришло в голову — это сделать фигуру (заливку) и потом внутри неё сделать вырез. Вариант с маской, насколько я понимаю, будет примерно таким же по количеству кода, но где-то читал, что это не так хорошо с т. з. производительности, как `clip-path`.

Comment: Интересно. Я ожидал наоборот, но может ты и прав.