# «Выесть» часть лайаута и закрасить прозрачным бэкграундом на CSS

Tags: css, svg

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, у меня есть лайаут, который покрывает весь body. Как можно очистить определенное место на этом лайауте и сделать его прозрачным?

На скриншоте показан пример лайаута:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Градиентной заливкой

Comment: Покажите где именно нужна прозрачность?

Comment: @Yuri в любом месте. в будущем хочу сдвигать эту область, хотел сделать отдельным блоком, но прозрачным не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи SVG, его внутреннего элемента `clipPath` + `clip-path` из CSS.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background-color: red;
}
.top {
  width:100%; height:500px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}
svg { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>

<svg height=0 width=0 viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1 
                       0,0 
                       .1,.1 .1,.9 .9,.9 .9,.1
                       .1,.1"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Чуть более подробное описание вырезания [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608616/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2-svg-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0/618342#618342).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!